# Installing/running .net business connector 2009 without a domain

Tags: .net, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, business-connector

Is there a way to run/install a .net business connector without a domain. It is for development only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Business Connector is only a DLL usable from Visual Studio... You can surely install it wherever you want but without a domain you won't be abble to connect to any AOS. You can use it for development in Visual Studio, but you can't test the code against the server.

You can install it on the server where you plan to run the tests and then copy/paste the DLL file from the install folder to your Visual Studio machine and reference it as usual (from a folder or from the windows assembly).

Be carefull of picking the right one as using a 32 bits version of the library may cause problems if you connect to a x64 server.

Comment: Actually I can't install it without a domain due to the installer. I could copy&paste it but it would fail on initialization.

Comment: Why would I need my computer to be in the domain? I mean I'd use domain credentials, just the (development) computer won't be in the domain.

Comment: The BC.NET is the core of an AX Client. Every AX client needs to be executed in a domain context. It may or may not be a good design idea, but it's a requirement. You can't execute an AX Client without a domain session, and the execution context will be this domain account. You don't need the machine in the domain, just the execution session (many times it doesn't work the "execute as another user"). This is why almost all the development stuff for AX is done directly in the AX servers...

Comment: May be you could inizialize the dll objects without a domain (I'm not sure) but surely you won't be abble to connect to the server, so the problem will remain.

Comment: So, just to double check, there is no way to pass domain credentials as it always use the current context?

Comment: "It may or may not be a good design idea". Actually it is a very bad and stupid decision. IMHO.

Comment: You got it. I agree with your opinion, it's easier and best solved in next versions but for 2009 is the way to go...